# which windows 10 is for the raspberry pi 2?

Tags: software-installation, windows, software-recommendation

I'm in the insider program. I have my raspberry pi2.
but there are several options for downloads. x86 vs 64 bit,  cpu vs phone.
but nothing says arm support. and all of them are 3GB + downloads.
I chose x64 for phone, and hope that is right. Anyone know for sure?

Comment: Microsoft has announced a preview release during BUILD 2015. It's called "Windows 10 IoT Core Insider Preview Image for Raspberry Pi 2". See [Have images for Windows 10 IOT been delivered yet?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29811/have-images-for-windows-10-iot-been-delivered-yet) for more details.

Comment: see my answer @j0h :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I chose x64 for phone

Nope.  The pi is not an x86-64 machine.  Microsoft has not released a version for the pi yet, but [has expressed the intention of doing so](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/featured/raspberrypi2support).  *[Later: They have now, follow that same link.]*

In other words, you will just have to wait.   Note there will likely *not* be a GUI desktop; it will be some sort of headless "embedded" OS.

Comment: And here, i thought MS was going to start making useful products again.

Comment: MSFT has a decent codebase for the ARM based devices, which is the retired Windows RT(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_RT) version. As it takes huge effort to make proper UI for a device, it is most likely that they would take "headless" code from the RT and turn it into embedded windows operating system. Likes of Raspbian but with better (or hopefully "full" or "amazing") integration with windows devices or even stack of technologies upon which "smart homes/cars/fridges" of  the future would be built.

Comment: @DimitryK While MS is known for establishing and exploiting monopolies,  I doubt enough people will buy exclusively into a windows based internet of things to turn smart whatever into IE vs. the world pt. 2.  Put another way, perhaps your vision here is a bit delusional ;) but that said, I agree the purpose of windows on the pi platform is for embedded development by people who are more comfortable with windows than anything else.  E.g., if I were a C# programmer, I imagine that's what I'd want.

Answer (score 3):

To get it IN THE FUTURE, sign up here:
https://www.windowsondevices.com/signup.aspx

The actual announcement page is here:
https://dev.windows.com/en-us/featured/raspberrypi2support

Answer (score 1):

The preview image and workaround can be founded in this pre release site:
http://ms-iot.github.io/content/win10/SetupRPI.htm

There you can download the Windows 10 image for Raspberry pi 2 on https://connect.microsoft.com/windowsembeddediot/SelfNomination.aspx?ProgramID=8558