# Have images for Windows 10 IOT been delivered yet?

Tags: windows-iot

Microsoft has announced that Windows 10 will be available for Raspberry Pi a while ago and there is there possibility to [register as IoT Developer](http://dev.windows.com/en-us/featured/raspberrypi2support/) .

But: has anyone already been provided with a pre-release of this image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update 2015-08-29:

The public release is now available from [MS-IoT GitHub](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/Downloads.htm).

---

During the 2015 BUILD conference, Microsoft announced the release of images Windows IoT for Raspberry Pi 2.  In order to obtain these images:

1. log into the Windows Connect website
2. join the 'Windows Embedded Pre-Release Programs'
3. Accept the user license agreements

From there you'll be able to access the [Downloads](https://connect.microsoft.com/windowsembeddedIoT/Downloads) section for Windows IoT.

To install Windows IoT follow [these instructions](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/win10/SetupRPI.htm).

Comment: Have you been able to Download an image for the Raspi from there? I can Filter for Builds, Documents and "All", but nothing will display any downloadable things.

Comment: @FragmentationNeeded in order to view the downloads, you HAVE to login into the connect website, join the program and accept the license agreements.  otherwise nothing will show.

Comment: There is also an active Bug Report (they call it "Feedback") concerning this: https://connect.microsoft.com/windowsembeddedIoT/Feedback/Details/1291749
However, my Dashboard now showed "Surveys" besides "Feedback" and "Remove from Dashboard"( suddenly, reason unknown). There I could find the EULA and accept it. Now, I've got the Downloads and my image. Mission accomplished.

Comment: IoT now in Preview - Quick tutorial here -http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/32185/894

Answer (score 2):

I've registered myself about 2 weeks ago and i haven't gotten a pre-release. I've searched on google for a while and haven't found any information about a possible pre-release.

Answer (score 2):

I have registered about 6 months ago. Still waiting with anticipation. They still in beta with KRE (vNext / .NET 5.0) -- Names keep changing. No communication from them yet and no sign of any image whatsoever on the dark net any where to be found. Must be a pretty damn good Non Disclosure or they just dont have a release candidate yet.

- Update 27/04/2015

I just checked my live account and I got a download link to Windows 10 Phone preview... that is almost the same version as on the Pi. So its close, very close!

- Update 03/06/2015

[We have a Preview of Windows IoT. I have made an alternative tutorial on Pi Exchange here on how to install it based on a few sources.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/32185/894)

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote a short description, how to install Windows 10 IoT Core on Raspberry Pi 2 in 5 minutes (if you're fast).
This also works on Win7, Win8, Linux and Mac OS.

https://coderwall.com/p/zchyog/how-to-install-windows-10-iot-core-on-raspberry-pi-2-in-5-minutes-also-works-on-win7-win8-linux-mac-os

Nitram509